# Query SQL distinct field with max date, returning all fields from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm having a hard time trying to get a query that sounds simple. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I have this table:

```
ID  Name  Date        Zone
----------------------------
01  AAA   01/01/2010  North
02  BBB   02/02/2010  South
03  AAA   05/01/2010  West
```

So, I need to filter the table to get distinct items (by Name), but, in case the item is repeated, get the one with the max date. Here is the result that I wanted to get from the example above:

```
ID  Name  Date        Zone
----------------------------
02  BBB   02/02/2010  South
03  AAA   05/01/2010  West
```

The problem is that I need to get all the fields from the table (I mean: Id, Name, Date and Zone should be returned from the query) once applied the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.columns
FROM table a
WHERE a.ID IN
(SELECT TOP 1 b.id FROM table b WHERE b.Name = a.Name ORDER BY b.Date DESC)
```

This will return the most recent row for each unique name.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTETable AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY [Date] DESC) ID
    FROM YourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM CTETable
WHERE ID = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select
  t.ID,
  t.Name,
  t.Date,
  t.Zone
from
  ThisTable t
  inner join
    (select 
      Name, 
      max(Date) as Date 
    from 
      ThisTable 
    group by 
      Name) x on x.Name = t.Name and x.Date = t.Date
```

Comment: This does not work if there are two records with a given name and the same max date.

Comment: @BillBarry In that case they both have the highest date and they are both returned. You may see that is incorrect, but it depends on the use case. Let's hope for now that the combination of `name` and `date` is unique. ;)